# Liquibase clearChecksums Could not find com.oracle.jdbc:ojdbc8:xx.x.x.x

Tags: java, gradle, liquibase, ojdbc

I would like to clear the checkSums for Liquibase. If I run the gradle command `gradle clearChecksums` I get an error.

```
Execution failed for task ':project-name:clearChecksums'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':project-name:liquibaseRuntime'.
> Could not find com.oracle.jdbc:ojdbc8:12.2.0.1.
        Required by:
        project :project-name
Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

Gradle

```
runtimeOnly 'com.oracle.ojdbc:ojdbc8:19.3.0.0'

liquibaseRuntime "com.oracle.jdbc:ojdbc8:12.2.0.1"
liquibaseRuntime 'org.liquibase:liquibase-core:3.8.1'

liquibaseRuntime 'org.liquibase.ext:liquibase-hibernate5:3.8'
liquibaseRuntime sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
liquibaseRuntime sourceSets.main.output
```

I've tried adding `"com.oracle.jdbc:ojdbc8:12.2.0.1"` as a dependency but it still can't find it.

```
implementation "com.oracle.jdbc:ojdbc8:12.2.0.1"
```

I'm assuming this is something obvious but I can't find anything online about it.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

what is the purpose of cleaning the chesum, if you want to force the re-execution of a changeset, you can delete the old record directly in the databasechangelog table.

Comment: I want to clear the checksum so it will recalculate new checksums without reexecuting the original statements. Also this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: You can create a new database, launch you app, then get a new checksum from databasechangelog of the new databse, update the old databaechangelog with news checksums

Comment: I know how I can clear the checksums in other ways. I would like to be able to do it using the gradle task. As a temporary solution I can directly call `liquibase.clearCheckSums()` but I would rather understand why the gradle task isn't working.